# Display an image when pressing a button in Qt GUI (Python)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I drew a GUI in Qt Creator, with a button, a slider and some labels.

What I am trying: when the button is pressed, print on terminal and in a label the modified value of the slider and display an image. As many webpages suggested, I am trying to display an image into a label by using the pixmap method. This is my whole code (the structure of the GUI is in the imported mainwindow.ui file)

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

qtCreatorFile = "mainwindow.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class myownGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


        #button
        self.Do_button.clicked.connect(self.action)

        #slider
        self.SLIDER.valueChanged[int].connect(self.SLIDER_update)

        #"global" variable init. by callback
        self.SLIDER_update()


    #The button callback
    def action(self):
        print "DOING ACTION!"
        print self.Slider
        #trying to display the image in the Image_label
        image = QtGui.QImage(QtGui.QImageReader(":/images/test.png").read())
        self.Image_label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(image))
        #self.Image_label.show() #unuseful command?


    #Slider update callback
    def SLIDER_update(self):
        self.Slider= self.SLIDER.value()
        if (self.Slider % 2 == 0): #even 
            self.Slider = self.Slider + 1
        self.Slider_label.setText(str(self.Slider))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = myownGUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code runs, it shows no error but the image is not displayed. 
I tried both JPG and PNG images. I tried also the simple image name, when the image is in the same folder.

What is wrong in my code? 
There is another way to display images in QT inside the GUI (with python) ?

Thank you in advance

Working with: Ubuntu 14.04 / Qt version 4.8.6

*I try to read all similar questions in stack overflow. It seems that my question is duplicated, but none of the answers seems to resolve my problem.*

**EDIT**: Using [PRMoureu's syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45414186/6564973) it works also when the image is the same folder, like

```
 image = QtGui.QImage(QtGui.QImageReader("./test.png").read())
```

Now the image is displayed and have only to be rescaled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the image with another path syntax :

```
image = QtGui.QImage(QtGui.QImageReader("./images/test.png").read())
```

or

```
image = QtGui.QImage(QtGui.QImageReader("images/test.png").read())
```